# Avoid if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I have 50 different classes. I made a generic class(All) with all these 50 classes.

```
public class All {

    private First first;
    private Second second;
    private Third third;
...


//GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

I have a generic method and inside this I have this piece of code:

```
 All all=new All();

       String result;
       if(all.getFirst()!=null){
           result=methodA(all.getFirst());
       }
       else if(all.getSecond()!=null){
           result=methodB(all.getSecond());
       }
       else if(all.getThird()!=null){
           result=methodC(all.getThird());
       }
...
```

I don´t like this configuration because it´s an unreadable code for so many classes.

How can I improve this code?

Comment: reflection may help you...

Comment: Look up Strategy and Factory method patterns.

Comment: you need to implement `get(int index)`, in the loop `for` you running for all elements and checking to null

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following piece of code is helpful for you:

```
 All all = new All();

 String result;

 for(int i = 0; i++ < all.length(); ) {
     YourInterface element = all.get(i);
     if(element != null)
         result = method(element);
 }
```

where,

- `length()` - amount of the classes
- `get(int index)` - access method to
  element from index
- `YourInterface` - common interface for all your
  classes

The next step is to use the reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely clean this up with either Reflection or creating your own version of that.
You'd have something like: all.getObjects(); Then have that bounce against a 2 dimensional array to grab the method needed to invoke then call that.

If I'll pop back in later to finish this up. but until then here's some things I found:

[using reflection to get objects from collection class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965102/using-reflection-to-get-objects-from-collection-class)

[What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = all.getFirst() != null ? methodA(all.getFirst())
   : all.getSecond() != null ? methodB(all.getSecond())
   : all.getThird() != null ? methodC(all.getThird())
   : null;
```